# How to load a Buy Now button that's in a HTML loaded via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

I'm having a hard time with this, and I'm afraid that the answer is easier than I think.

Here's the thing: I'm loading different sections of a user zone with ajax (replacing the contents of a `<div>`). One of this sections is about payments, and Buy Now buttons will be used to pay the items that are shown.

I have the code from http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/. I tested it and it works fine, but not when I put that code within the payments section. The console says that the .js is being called, and the .js is in the response, but nothing is shown.

Doing some research, it looks that this is for security reasons, but can't this be overridden somehow?

Also, what confuses me more, is that I have some other scripting being done in this section, and it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry, this is not a proper answer to the question, but I worked it around by using `PAYPAL.apps.ButtonFactory.create();` as shown in https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons#javascript-api

I'm not happy though.